# UWP Blank app throws error code: The app didn't start.. Activation phase: COM ActivateExtension

Tags: uwp, c++-winrt

I'm trying to integrate a existing DLL project (3rd party dependencies) to Blank UWP. The Blank App project build fine but throws error when it is lauched.

In Event Viewer, log suggests Error code: The app didn't start.. Activation phase: COM ActivateExtension.

Below is the article about "How to: Use existing C++ code in a Universal Windows Platform app" which states that UWP Apps run in a protected environment. As a result, many Win32, COM, and CRT API calls that might compromise platform security aren't allowed. The /ZW compiler option can detect such calls and generate an error. You can use the App Certification Kit on your application to detect code that calls disallowed APIs. For more information, see Windows App Certification Kit****.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/how-to-use-existing-cpp-code-in-a-universal-windows-platform-app?view=msvc-170

does that mean DLL project can't be integrated?

Comment: *"does that mens DLL project can't be integrated?"* - No, it means that your DLL cannot call APIs that aren't available under the UWP application model.

Comment: Any idea, how to verify if C++ project library is compatible for UWP project?

Comment: You could use [DUMPBIN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dumpbin-reference) to list the imports and see if anything stands out. I don't know of a tool that does that automatically. Maybe there's something in the WACK that works with DLLs.